# Create WPF Vertical icon navigation

Tags: c#, wpf

`enter code here`I'm looking to create a WPF interface similar to this image. What WPF controls would I need to use to achieve this?

[image]

```
<Window x:Class="Example1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Example1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid Background="#FFFDFDFD">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="200"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid Background="#FF0052F0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="50">

    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: It's my first WPF project so I'm unsure whether this is correct or not! I've edited the orignal post to provide additional details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to answer your question:

> What WPF controls would I need to use to achieve this?

The blue area is a TabControl with the tabs placed at the left side (TabStripPlacement="Left"). You have to edit the template to make it look like that on the picture, that will be possible with very few lines of XAML code.

At the top right is also a TabControl, this time with the default tab position but again with a changed style. Then, a separator comes. You can also use a Rectangle with Height="1" and SnapsToDevicePixels="True".

The next thing is an Image, but I'm not sure (that with the Skype logo). The next element is a TextBlock (or Label) with a huge FontSize. Then you can see a few CheckBoxes and at the bottom, there are two Buttons (you can also use Hyperlinks, but Buttons are easier to work with).

I hope that answers your question.